# CDI can not inject pojo java class. (Unsatisfied dependencies for type Pojo with qualifiers @Default)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle, cdi

Hi i have a problem with inject a regular java class (Pojo class) into EJB bean.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DomainRouteFinderService {

    @Inject
    private Pojo pojo;

    private AtomicInteger sequencer;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        sequencer = new AtomicInteger();
        sequencer.lazySet(0);
    }

    @Produces
    @Named("sequencer")
    public String getText(){
        return "Number: "+ sequencer.getAndIncrement();
    }
}
```

Pojo class:

```
public class Pojo {
}
```

In my multiprojects with structure like below:

ROOT - ear

1. ejb
2. web

Web module depends on ejb.

In web module is beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="all"

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my problem by adding another beans.xml to ejb.
I put this file to 
main/java/resources/META-INF localization.

Why?

> One of the most significant changes in CD 1.1/Java EE 7 is that by
>   popular request, CDI is now enabled by default. This means that
>   there's no need to explicitly add a beans.xml to enable DI any more.
>   However, it is also very important to understand that CDI now also
>   provides finer grained control over component scanning via the
>   'bean-discovery-mode' attribute. This attribute has three possible
>   values:
>
> ```
> 'annotated' - loosely translated, means that only components with a class-level annotation are processed.
> 'all' - all components are processed, just like they were in Java EE 6 with the explicit beans.xml.
> 'none' - CDI is effectively disabled.
> ```
>
> By default, if you specify nothing and there is no beans.xml, the bean
>   discovery mode of 'annotated' and not 'all' is assumed.

But i want to one beans.xml for ejb module and war module.

Comment: CDI is configured separately for each module, that's the way it is. Of you do not add another beans.xml into the ejb module, the only way to insert your Pojo is to annotate it by `@Dependent` annotation - this is default scope CDI beans, but you need to be explicit so that CDI considers your POJO as a bean without additional beans.xml. If you cannot modify your Pojo, you might create a CDI producer for it.

Comment: So my solution is ok?

Comment: Do you really need to deploy as an EAR? You can now deploy your EJBs inside of WAR files.

Comment: The solution is OK, there is nothing wrong with having multiple beans.xml. In JavaEE6 this was the only option.